# React Native app works on iOS but comes up with error on Android posts.map not defined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have created a simple program to display information from my website on the app. It works on iOS but on my Android device an error shows up :
posts.map is not a function. This is my code:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  ActivityIndicator,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Header,
} from 'react-native';

let lw = 100;

import Img from 'react-image';

let li = 'https://www.teanewsnetwork.com/profileicons/';
let bean = 'azure.jpg';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    error: false,
    posts: [],
  };

  componentWillMount = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://www.teanewsnetwork.com/api/fetcharticles.php?code=#NIL7*GKD60JTRTEFZ0CkvpHMJJW^-9q&starting=0&limit=40'
      );
      const posts = await response.json();

      this.setState({ loading: false, posts });
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({ loading: false, error: true });
    }
  };

  renderPost = ({ id, title, content, authorimage, authorname }, i) => {
    let b = { authorname };
    return (
      <View style={styles.postContent}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column',
            textAlign: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text style={styles.postauthor}>{title} </Text>

          <Image
            source={{
              uri: `https://teanewsnetwork.com/profileicons/${authorimage}`,
            }}
            defaultSource={require('./contact-outline.png')}
            style={{
              width: lw,
              height: lw,
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              borderRadius: lw / 2,
            }}
          />

          <Text style={styles.postauthor}>{authorname}</Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.postBody}>{content}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const {posts, loading, error} = this.state

    if (loading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.center}>
          <ActivityIndicator animating={true} />
        </View>
      )
    }

    if (error) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.center}>
          <Text>
            Failed to load posts!
          </Text>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        {posts.map(this.renderPost)}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    borderBottomColor: 'red',

    top: 100,
    zIndex: 6,
  },

  postauthor: {
    flex: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    borderBottomColor: 'red',
    paddingVertical: 25,
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingRight: 15,
    left: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },

  postContent: {
    flex: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 20,
    borderBottomColor: '#EEE',
    borderRadius: 4,

    fontSize: 18,
    left: 0,
    paddingRight: 15,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  postBody: {
    marginTop: 1,
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'black',
    left: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  center: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

I am a beginner coder on react native and would like to have some help here. The code works on iOS emulator with EXPO but doesnt work on my Android Device.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `posts` is not a array, check the type of `posts`.